# Difference between configure and qmake

Tags: qt, build, configure, qmake

I am studying build script of QT libraries:

```
@echo off

echo Setting up a MinGW/Qt only environment...
echo -- QTDIR set to E:\QT\4.8.4
echo -- PATH set to E:\QT\4.8.4\bin
echo -- Adding e:\MinGW\bin to PATH
echo -- Adding %SystemRoot%\System32 to PATH
echo -- QMAKESPEC set to win32-g++

set QTDIR=E:\QT\4.8.4
set PATH=E:\QT\4.8.4\bin
set PATH=%PATH%;e:\MinGW\bin
set PATH=%PATH%;%SystemRoot%\System32
set QMAKESPEC=win32-g++

if not "%1"=="compile_debug" goto END
cd %QTDIR%
echo This will configure and compile qt in debug.
echo The release libraries will not be recompiled.
pause
configure -plugin-sql-sqlite -plugin-sql-odbc -qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg
REM cd %QTDIR%\src
REM qmake
REM mingw32-make debug
:END
```

To determine function of particular commands I have commented remaining parts of file. I noticed that configure.exe command traverses directory structure of QT source codes and creates makefiles for every project file *.pro it finds. From [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-manual.html) I remember that this should be task of qmake tool:

`qmake automates the generation of Makefiles`

What's the difference between configure.exe and qmake.exe? Isn't qmake call in build script redundant? I am a bit confused.

Answer (score 1):

`qmake` does primarily run the Makefile generation process, but it also ties in with the `moc` process as well instead of just generating Makefile's.